# Powershell copy vs move cmd

Tags: powershell, asynchronous

I'm running into some issues with my existing powershell script that copies data from a remote location into a local folder - that local folder also happens to be sync'd with google drive for desktop.

I'm seeing incomplete files being uploaded etc. In order to combat this I think it would be easier/better to change where the initial remote > local is putting its files, and instead of copying directly into the sync folder - copy into a temp/staging location that's NOT the sync folder.

Once that process is complete then use the powershell move-cmd to simply 'move' which will just update file locators to be that of the sync folder.

I think this will solve my issue.

Anyone see any problems with this approach?

Comment: The fastest way to assess whether the proposed solution is gonna work under your specific circumstances is for you to _just go ahead and test it_ - having people opine over it on the internet won't make a difference :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have ruled out device connectivity, multiple files being uploaded at once vs. a single file being uploaded, and mobile device app or internet browser there is nothing wrong with your approach. If you need anymore assistance please reply to this thread or mark this as the answer.